# Button not responding to taps inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton

I have a custom TableViewCell with a button. Before switching to dynamic cells, this button worked fine. However, now the button is unselectable.

The button doesn't even highlight on touch.

The best part? If i disable AutoLayout, while the button appears at the very top of the viewcontroller, almost too small to touch... it works

Event attempting to remove autolayout and programmatically changing the position of the button within the cell like this, doesn't work:

Button.frame.origin.x = self.contentView.frame.width / 2

The code for my button:

```
class HotelRateCell: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var hotelRateTitle: UILabel!    
   @IBOutlet weak var hotelRatePrice: UILabel!    
   @IBOutlet weak var type: UILabel!    
   @IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      //tried both enabled and disabled
      self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)   
   }
}
```

And the code for the actual action

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: HotelRateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HotelRateCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HotelRateCell

    cell.reservationButton.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "reservationButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.reservationButton.addTarget(self, action: "reservationButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

 func reservationButton(sender: UIButton!) {
    if sender.tag == 0 {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://reddit.com")!)
        println("rservation button pressed")

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the frame of the cell and the button? Maybe your cell has a height of 0 and `clipsSubviews` set to `false` and that's why the button is not clickable. Also using the `indexPath.row` as the tag is not such a good idea, because the tag default value is 0.

Comment: thanks for the pointer on the indexPath.row, i'm not too familiar with view debugging, the height is definitely not 0. Not too sure what clilpsSuviews does though?

Comment: @CatalinaT. I can confirm though that clipsSubviews is not disabled on the contentView, and I also enabled it on the button to experiment but nothing happened

Comment: The fact that is not disabled might be the problem. Try setting it to true for the cell and the contentView and see if you can still see the content of the cell. Also, could you add the code where you are calculating the cell's height? Maybe the problem is there